# Vue Resource root options not used?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I specify a root options in my Vue-Resource in my main.js file, but when I do the request, it does not use the root options. What am I missing ?

Here's the code :

main.js:

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://api.domain.com/v1/'
```

In a component :

```
ready: function () {
    console.log(this.$http.options.root) // Correctly show 'http://api.domain.com/v1/'

    this.$http.get('/members/', null, { // FAILS because it tries to load /members/ in the current domain
        headers: {'auth-token': 'abcde'}
    }).then(function (xhr) {
        // process ...
    })
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I'm using Vue.js v1.0.15 and Vue-Resource v0.6.1

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 59):

Ohoh this is tricky !

In order for root to be taken into consideration, you need to remove the initial `/` from the url :

`this.$http.get('/members/')` **becomes** `this.$http.get('members/')`

Also, you need to remove the last `/` in the root :

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://api.domain.com/v1/'
```

becomes

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://api.domain.com/v1'
```

And with that, it will work!

Comment: LOL, thanks. i also was struggling why root not working.